# Match a digit between 2 lines

Tags: perl

Can anyone help me match a digit in Perl that has a new line before it and a new line after (and is only that digit on the raw) I have tried this `/^[\d\n]+$/` but it matches all the new lines...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just:

```
/\n\d\n/
```

If you want to use `^` and `$` you would need to specify the /m flag and get rid of the `\n` in the character class (leaving just \d, so it wouldn't even need to be in a character class):

```
/^\d$/m
```

(But that would match a digit alone on a line even at the beginning or end of the string (without a newline before or after it).

Answer (score 0):

How about this regular expression

```
/^(\d)$/
```

If I understand you correctly, you want to return true when a row contains a digit and only a digit.